# Fetch the appropriate superscript values given in a string

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Since I am stuck with the superscripts to map the values accordingly with the superscript provided.

Here is the small paragraph

Rachel E. Miller1, Richard J. Miller2, Abdelhak Belmadani3, Suzanne Golub4, Amanda J. Fosang4 and Anne-Marie Malfait5, 1Biochemistry, Rush University Medical Center, Chicago, IL, 2Molecular Biochemistry and Pharmacology, Northwestern University, Chicago, IL, 3Northwestern University, Chicago, IL, 4University of Melbourne, Melbourne, Australia, 5Rush University Medeical Center, Chicago, IL

Actually this is fetched from an HTML page using Jsoup and i have Stored in a String!

Can You friends assist me and provide me solution to map the values such as

Rachel E. Miller = Biochemistry, Rush University Medical Center, Chicago, IL

as shown above ... Need to match the same superscript value

Thanks in advance..

Comment: If all of your information is stored in a `string` then the question has nothing to do with `HTML` or `jsoup`. Start with splitting the string by commas and thn find the matching numbers. There are plenty of resources for this on SO and of course google.

Comment: No Actually i need to map Name and affiliation with superscript. How is it achievable